# Stop child overflowing parent

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I have a page with a sidebar. The sidebar content overflows the page, so I've added `overflow-y: hidden` and `max-height: 100vh` to `main` and `overflow-y: auto` to the list group to make it scroll but that does not work. The overflowing content is cut off but the scroll bar is not there.

```css
main {
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.scrollarea {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <header class="col-12 navbar navbar-dark sticky-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap p-0 shadow">
      <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <div class="nav-item text-nowrap justify-self-end">
          <a class="nav-link px-3" href="#">Sign out</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

    <div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="row flex-grow-1">
        <div class="col-md-4 border-end gx-0 d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-2 border-bottom">
            <h2>Placeholder</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="list-group list-group-flush scrollarea">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active">
              <div class="">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                  <strong>Title</strong>
                  <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-danger">10</span>
                </div>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa velit necessitatibus eveniet blanditiis eum maxime odio autem labore omnis repudiandae cumque explicabo nisi suscipit iste rem, a sapiente voluptas incidunt?</p>
              </div>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
              <div class="">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                  <strong>Title</strong>
                  <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-danger">10</span>
                </div>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa velit necessitatibus eveniet blanditiis eum maxime odio autem labore omnis repudiandae cumque explicabo nisi suscipit iste rem, a sapiente voluptas incidunt?</p>
              </div>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
              <div class="">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                  <strong>Title</strong>
                  <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-danger">10</span>
                </div>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa velit necessitatibus eveniet blanditiis eum maxime odio autem labore omnis repudiandae cumque explicabo nisi suscipit iste rem, a sapiente voluptas incidunt?</p>
              </div>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
              <div class="">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                  <strong>Title</strong>
                  <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-danger">10</span>
                </div>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa velit necessitatibus eveniet blanditiis eum maxime odio autem labore omnis repudiandae cumque explicabo nisi suscipit iste rem, a sapiente voluptas incidunt?</p>
              </div>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
              <div class="">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                  <strong>Title</strong>
                  <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-danger">10</span>
                </div>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa velit necessitatibus eveniet blanditiis eum maxime odio autem labore omnis repudiandae cumque explicabo nisi suscipit iste rem, a sapiente voluptas incidunt?</p>
              </div>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
              <div class="">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                  <strong>Title</strong>
                  <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-danger">10</span>
                </div>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa velit necessitatibus eveniet blanditiis eum maxime odio autem labore omnis repudiandae cumque explicabo nisi suscipit iste rem, a sapiente voluptas incidunt?</p>
              </div>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
              <div class="">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                  <strong>Title</strong>
                  <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-danger">10</span>
                </div>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa velit necessitatibus eveniet blanditiis eum maxime odio autem labore omnis repudiandae cumque explicabo nisi suscipit iste rem, a sapiente voluptas incidunt?</p>
              </div>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
              <div class="">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                  <strong>Title</strong>
                  <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-danger">10</span>
                </div>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa velit necessitatibus eveniet blanditiis eum maxime odio autem labore omnis repudiandae cumque explicabo nisi suscipit iste rem, a sapiente voluptas incidunt?</p>
              </div>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
              <div class="">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                  <strong>Title</strong>
                  <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-danger">10</span>
                </div>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa velit necessitatibus eveniet blanditiis eum maxime odio autem labore omnis repudiandae cumque explicabo nisi suscipit iste rem, a sapiente voluptas incidunt?</p>
              </div>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
              <div class="">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                  <strong>Title</strong>
                  <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-danger">10</span>
                </div>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa velit necessitatibus eveniet blanditiis eum maxime odio autem labore omnis repudiandae cumque explicabo nisi suscipit iste rem, a sapiente voluptas incidunt?</p>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          main content
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I make the sidebar scrollable, preferably using Bootstrap classes?

Comment: I managed to get your desired behavior with a wide screen, but it wont show your main content on a small screen. Just sorting out the mess to get that far was an hour and a half long headache. Then I realized, this is a headache for which the holder deserves to be paid. Hire someone (I'd consider it at $50+/hr) otherwise good luck.

Comment: For the scrollable sidebar area, is it include/exclude the 'Placeholder' ? And you prefer not to use any `height` css property at all ?

Comment: @Zeikman it doesn't include placeholder and I'd rather not use height property

Comment: what about setting `main { height: 100vh; }`, is it alright ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a sample using `flexbox` trick with some `position` property to achieve that, and ***please do take note that the sample here is not covering the topic of responsive layout in small screen view***.

1. Use `flex` css to prepare the layout structure (header, sidebar, main content)
2. Then use `position` on the scrollable area: an `absolute` box within a `relative` container

Hope it helps and Happy coding!

```css
main {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="d-flex flex-column">
    <header class="col-12 navbar navbar-dark sticky-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap p-0 shadow">
      <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <div class="nav-item text-nowrap justify-self-end">
          <a class="nav-link px-3" href="#">Sign out</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

    <div class="flex-grow-1 container-fluid d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="row flex-grow-1">
        <div class="col-md-4 border-end gx-0 d-flex flex-column">
        
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-2 border-bottom">
            <h2>Placeholder</h2>
          </div>
          
          <div class="flex-grow-1 position-relative">
            <div class="position-absolute w-100 h-100 overflow-y-auto">           
              <div class="list-group list-group-flush scrollarea">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active">
                  <div class="">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                      <strong>Title</strong>
                      <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-danger">10</span>
                    </div>
                    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa velit necessitatibus eveniet blanditiis eum maxime odio autem labore omnis repudiandae cumque explicabo nisi suscipit iste rem, a sapiente voluptas incidunt?</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                  <div class="">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                      <strong>Title</strong>
                      <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-danger">10</span>
                    </div>
                    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa velit necessitatibus eveniet blanditiis eum maxime odio autem labore omnis repudiandae cumque explicabo nisi suscipit iste rem, a sapiente voluptas incidunt?</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                  <div class="">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                      <strong>Title</strong>
                      <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-danger">10</span>
                    </div>
                    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa velit necessitatibus eveniet blanditiis eum maxime odio autem labore omnis repudiandae cumque explicabo nisi suscipit iste rem, a sapiente voluptas incidunt?</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                  <div class="">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                      <strong>Title</strong>
                      <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-danger">10</span>
                    </div>
                    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa velit necessitatibus eveniet blanditiis eum maxime odio autem labore omnis repudiandae cumque explicabo nisi suscipit iste rem, a sapiente voluptas incidunt?</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                  <div class="">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                      <strong>Title</strong>
                      <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-danger">10</span>
                    </div>
                    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa velit necessitatibus eveniet blanditiis eum maxime odio autem labore omnis repudiandae cumque explicabo nisi suscipit iste rem, a sapiente voluptas incidunt?</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                  <div class="">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                      <strong>Title</strong>
                      <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-danger">10</span>
                    </div>
                    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa velit necessitatibus eveniet blanditiis eum maxime odio autem labore omnis repudiandae cumque explicabo nisi suscipit iste rem, a sapiente voluptas incidunt?</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                  <div class="">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                      <strong>Title</strong>
                      <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-danger">10</span>
                    </div>
                    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa velit necessitatibus eveniet blanditiis eum maxime odio autem labore omnis repudiandae cumque explicabo nisi suscipit iste rem, a sapiente voluptas incidunt?</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                  <div class="">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                      <strong>Title</strong>
                      <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-danger">10</span>
                    </div>
                    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa velit necessitatibus eveniet blanditiis eum maxime odio autem labore omnis repudiandae cumque explicabo nisi suscipit iste rem, a sapiente voluptas incidunt?</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                  <div class="">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                      <strong>Title</strong>
                      <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-danger">10</span>
                    </div>
                    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa velit necessitatibus eveniet blanditiis eum maxime odio autem labore omnis repudiandae cumque explicabo nisi suscipit iste rem, a sapiente voluptas incidunt?</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                  <div class="">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                      <strong>Title</strong>
                      <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-danger">10</span>
                    </div>
                    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa velit necessitatibus eveniet blanditiis eum maxime odio autem labore omnis repudiandae cumque explicabo nisi suscipit iste rem, a sapiente voluptas incidunt?</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          main content
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```